# node mongoose how to get a full list of schemas (documents and subdocuments )

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I know that I can get a full list of models using modelNames() :

```
console.log('MODELS: %j', mongoose.modelNames());
```

Is there any way to get a full list of schemas

i.e.  with the following User model

```
const Role = new mongoose.Schema({ .... });
const Permission = new mongoose.Schema({ .... });

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { ...  },
  roles: [Role],
  permissions: [Permission]
});
```

I would like to get an Array object like ['Role', 'Permission']

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Schema definitions...

const schemas = [];
mongoose.modelNames().forEach(function(modelName){
    schemas.push(mongoose.model(modelName).schema.obj);
})

console.log(schemas);
```